# Facebook share button doesn't open dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to make facebook share button. Problem is when I click on the button it doesn't open anything. Doesn't open share dialog window. Here is what I have. My button

```
<a class="share-fb" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareFB( encodeURIComponent(\'http://example.com/'.$url.'\'), '.$row['image_title'].', encodeURIComponent(\'http://example.com/\') );"></a>
```

The js part

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'MYID',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        var lang        = 'BG';
        var prPath      = '/';
        var prjUrl      = 'http://example.com/';
        var fpath       = 'http://example.com/';            
        var PROTOCOL    = 'http://';            
        var SESSION     = '';           

        // Preload some heavy images if necessarilly 
        var preload = [

        ];

        var ploaded = [];

        $(preload).each(function(i, r){
            ploaded[i]      = new Image();
            ploaded[i].src  = '/img/'+r;
        });

        function shareFB(url,title,img)
        {
            if(!title) title = '';
            var i = (img) ? unescape(img) : 'http://example.com/img/logo.png';
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: title,
                description: 'description',
                caption:'wwww.example.com',
                picture: i,
                link: unescape(url)
            },function(r){});
            return false;
        }                       
    </script>
```

The error in console that I've got is `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` but I can't see where is this `)` missing..

CSS

```
#gallery-nav span a.share-fb {
     background: url("../img/fb.png") no-repeat center center;
     background-size: contain;
}
```

Here is how I generate the URI Component in the button code:

```
$url = 'category-'.$row['img_category'].'/image-'.$row['image_id'].'.html'

<a class="share-fb" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareFB( encodeURIComponent(\'http://example.com/'.$url.'\'), '.$row['image_title'].', encodeURIComponent(\'http://example.com/\') );"></a>
```

And the JS + CSS is above..

HTML output

```
<a class="share-fb" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareFB( encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/category-2/image-828.html'), image title, encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/') );"></a>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS dependencies to get this button to appear? I can't replicate the problem

Comment: Also when you click the button does it reach your `shareFB` function?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with css which load the image.

Comment: The error is happening **when I click on the button**

Comment: I am fairly certain the problem is with your hyperlink, in the `onclick` section. Hard for me to test because of the `PHP` you have. You can debug to see if it reaches your `shareFB` function so you know where the problem is

Comment: I'm also think that the problem is in `onClick` section. How can I check if is reaching the `shareFB`? I've tried to put alert in the function but got errors..

Comment: If you can use chrome or a browser with debug tools then you can open developer console and put a break point on the first line of the function. If it gets that far you know the `onclick` is not the problem.

Comment: I'm on Chrome but can't see where is this in dev console..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120692/discussion-between-ajenkins-and-garg).

Comment: Show us what the actual HTML code of the link looks like,

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my question. It's really only this..

Comment: That is (presumably) PHP code, otherwise it would not have stuff like `'.$row['image_title'].'` in it. Show us the _output_ of that PHP script that the browser receives.

Comment: Updated with html output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `onclick`, using the following code will work. Adjust your variables to conform to this pattern.

---

```
<a class="share-fb" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareFB( encodeURIComponent(''), '', encodeURIComponent('') );"></a>
```

Comment: Thank's. The problem is in `'` and `"` and after your working example with empty strings and your help with debugging I was able to make it to work.

Answer (score -1):

},function(r){}); there is missing ")" }),function(r){});

Comment: It is not this.. When I add this `)` there got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`